# Difference in including css,js,google fonts in Magento 2.1.x and 2.2.x

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2

Magento 2.1.x and 2.2.x have different ways of including scripts

Answer (score 0):

Scripts and css can be included in ***default_head_blocks.xml*** file of layout in theme or any custom module.

**Magento 2.1.x**

```
<css src="css/default.css" />       <!-- CSS -->
<link src="js/theme-script.js"/>    <!-- JS -->
<!-- Google Fonts -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,500,700,400italic,700italic|Muli:400,400italic" src_type="url"  />
```

**Magento 2.2.x**

```
<css src="css/default.css" />       <!-- CSS -->
<script src="js/theme-script.js"/>  <!-- JS -->
<!-- Google Fonts -->
<link rel="stylesheet" src="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,500,700,400italic,700italic|Muli:400,400italic" src_type="url"  />
```

For js "script" tag is used instead of "link"

For external google fonts "src" is used instead of "href" for fonts